# use for loop in phpexcel cell and print all email ids froom the array

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

```
$this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','Name');
$this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1','Email');

foreach ($variable as $k){
$this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A',$k['name']);
$this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B',$k['email']);
}
```

but $k['email'] is an array and how to use forloop inside the cell to print email ids

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to print each `$k` name and email into subsequent rows, one email per row. You can then use something like this;

```
$this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','Name');
$this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1','Email');

$row = 2;
foreach ($variable as $k){
    $this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A$row",$k['name']);
    $this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("B$row",$k['email']);
    $row++;
}
```

You put column headings in row 1, then put actual values in rows 2 onward - variable `$row` keeps track of what row you're putting things into.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print **all emails** in one cell - you can [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) array to string:

```
$this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(
    'B', 
    implode('; ', $k['email'])
);
```